# n! divides a product: Part II

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, matrices

This is a follow up on [another MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265438/n-divides-a-product).

> **Question.** For $n\geq2$, the following is always an integer. Is it not?
>   $$\frac{(2^n-2)(2^{n-1}-2)\cdots(2^3-2)(2^2-2)}{n!}.$$

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As $S_n$ also embeds in $GL_{n-1}({\mathbb F}_2)$, you only need to check that $n!$ is not divisible by $2^n$.

Comment: But it never is.

Comment: (1) It is possible for $2^{n-1}$ to divide $n!$. (2) $\mathfrak{S}_n$ embeds in $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_2)$ as permutation matrices, but how does it embed in $GL_{n-1}(\mathbb{F}_2)$? (3) At any rate, although I like to approach again, however this answer need more details. I wish it works.

Comment: If $V={\mathbb F}_2^n$ with the permutation action of $S_n$ and $W$ is the subspace of $V$ spanned by $(1,1,\ldots,1)$, then $W$ is $S_n$-invariant and thus $S_n$ acts on $V/W$.  The almost simplicity of $S_n$ guarantees that this action is faithful for all $n>4$, and you can check the smaller cases.

Comment: Incidentally, there's a subspace $X$ of $V$ consisting of all vectors whose entries sum to zero that is also invariant under $S_{n}$. If $n$ is even, then $X$ contains $W$ and this gives an embedding of $S_{n}$ into $GL_{n-2}(\mathbb{F}_{2})$ (provided $n > 4$) and as a corollary, one gets that $\frac{(2^{n} - 4)(2^{n-1}-4) \cdots (2^{3}-4)}{n!}$ is an integer for $n$ even and $n \geq 4$.

Comment: Just to explain the last part of John's answer: the group-theoretic argument shows that the quotient $Q=(2^n-2) \cdots (2^2-2)/n!$ is an odd integer times $2^m$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since $n!$ is not divisible by $2^n$, we have $v_2(n!) \leq n-1$ so that $v_2(Q) \geq 0$.

Comment: With a curious coincidence I just read the very statement (that $2^n$ does not divide $n!$ for $n\geq 1$) in my notes from my classes for preparation for the mathematical olympiade. The proof is by induction: if $n$ is odd, and $2^n|n!$, then clearly $2^n | (n-1)!$, a contradiction. If $n=2k$ and $2^{2k} | (2k)!$, then we write $(2k)!$ as $(1\cdot 3\cdots (2k-1))\cdot (2\cdot4\cdot\cdots 2k$. The first $k$ odd numbers can be left out, and we get that $2^{2k}$ divides $2\cdots 2k=2^k\cdot k!$, i.e., $2^k$ divides $k!$, a contradiction.

Comment: @PéterKomjáth: Legendre's formula gives the $2$-adic valuation $\nu_2(n!)=n-s(n)$ where $s(n)$ is the binary digits of $n$. But, $s(n)\geq1$ for $n\geq1$. That means $\nu_2(n!)\leq n-1$. In other words, at best $2^{n-1}$ divides $n!$ but never $2^n$ divides $n!$.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a direct number theoretic proof. First of all note that
$$(2^n-2)(2^{n-1}-2)\cdots(2^2-2)=2^{n-1}(2^{n-1}-1)(2^{n-2}-1)\cdots(2^1-1).$$
Now for any prime $p$ we have, by [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula) and by [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem),
$$v_p(n!)\leq\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{p-1}\right\rfloor\leq v_p\bigl(2^{n-1}(2^{n-1}-1)(2^{n-2}-1)\cdots(2^1-1)\bigr),$$
where for the second inequality we argue separately for $p=2$ and for $p\geq 3$. The result follows.

**P.S.** The above proof was inspired by [Cherng-tiao Perng](https://mathoverflow.net/users/104791/cherng-tiao-perng)'s deleted response (which was not entirely correct).

Comment: Indeed.  I should have seen this and mentioned to Cherng-tiao how to fix it. Gerhard "Tenders His Most Sincere Apologies" Paseman, 2017.03.24.